# Significance test for Yule's Q

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, ranks, goodman-kruskal-gamma

It says [here](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/gamma-coefficient-goodman-kruskal/) that the test statistic for [Goodman and Kruskal's gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodman_and_Kruskal%27s_gamma) is

$z=G\sqrt{\frac{n_c+n_d}{N(1-G^2)}},$

where $n_c$ and $n_d$ are the numbers of concordant and discordant pairs, resp.

Translated to the case of Yule's Q, this should be

$z=Q\sqrt{\frac{ad+bc}{N(1-Q^2)}}.$

In either case, this is undefined whenever $Q^2=1$ regardless of $N$.

Given for example $N=2$ and $a=d=1$, I get $Q=1$.  Intuitively, I should get a very low significance if $N=2$ no matter the score value.  Instead, significance is undefined.

That seems wrong.  What am I missing?